# How to resolve `Error: Command was killed with SIGABRT (Aborted): npm i prisma@5.9.1 -D`?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

We had to change a few things on our app while rebranding (just domain name, nothing major). Pushing the app to the same repo, branch somehow threw an error. Now, the error is `Error: Command was killed with SIGABRT (Aborted): npm i prisma@5.9.1 -D`. I have tried a few things to resolve the issue including adding  `"prod": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 index.js"` to my `package.json` file, ran `node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js` in the terminal - which somehow threw it's own error:

```
AFVFHGQBRQ6L7 frontend % node --max-old-space-size=4096 pages/index.js
file:///path-to-app/frontend/pages/index.js:17
    <div>
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:167:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:30)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21)

Node.js v21.5.0
```

even though there isn't any 'unexpected token'...
Here is the latest error that I am hoping you can help resolve:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[30523:0x128008000]   242711 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 2047.3 (2090.3) -> 2046.2 (2090.3) MB, 209.88 / 0.00 ms  (+ 15.7 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 247 ms) (average mu = 0.534, current mu = 0.[30523:0x128008000]   243059 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 2047.1 (2090.3) -> 2047.0 (2090.8) MB, 207.08 / 0.00 ms  (+ 0.3 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 212 ms) (average mu = 0.475, current mu = 0.4

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0x104356930 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x1044f9998 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x1046da178 v8::internal::Heap::stack() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x1046d8388 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x1046cf674 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x1046cff10 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x1046b3594 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x1046a6d18 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithMap(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x104969b70 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary> v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary>, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10496aa10 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary> v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add<v8::internal::Isolate, (v8::internal::AllocationType)0>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, v8::internal::InternalIndex*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10496a6bc v8::internal::BaseNameDictionary<v8::internal::NameDictionary, v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NameDictionary>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, v8::internal::InternalIndex*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x104947aa0 v8::internal::LookupIterator::ApplyTransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x104978f50 v8::internal::Object::TransitionAndWriteDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x104978b80 v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::internal::EnforceDefineSemantics) [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x1048f1a80 v8::internal::JSObject::DefineOwnPropertyIgnoreAttributes(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::JSObject::AccessorInfoHandling, v8::internal::EnforceDefineSemantics, v8::internal::StoreOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
16: 0x1048f17bc v8::internal::JSObject::DefineOwnPropertyIgnoreAttributes(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::JSObject::AccessorInfoHandling, v8::internal::EnforceDefineSemantics) [/usr/local/bin/node]
17: 0x1047c4b4c v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned char>::BuildJsonObject(v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned char>::JsonContinuation const&, v8::base::SmallVector<v8::internal::JsonProperty, 16ul, std::__1::allocator<v8::internal::JsonProperty>> const&, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
18: 0x1047c1d74 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned char>::ParseJsonValue<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
19: 0x1047bf844 v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned char>::ParseJson(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
20: 0x1047bf764 v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned char>::Parse(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
21: 0x104583ab8 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonParse(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
22: 0x104e1b854 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
23: 0x10aa52844 
24: 0x104dc7b10 Builtins_AsyncFunctionAwaitResolveClosure [/usr/local/bin/node]
25: 0x104e812d8 Builtins_PromiseFulfillReactionJob [/usr/local/bin/node]
26: 0x104db6654 Builtins_RunMicrotasks [/usr/local/bin/node]
27: 0x104d8e794 Builtins_JSRunMicrotasksEntry [/usr/local/bin/node]
28: 0x10463bee4 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::Invoke(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeParams const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
29: 0x10463c394 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithTryCatch(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeParams const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
30: 0x10463c540 v8::internal::Execution::TryRunMicrotasks(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
31: 0x104664150 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::RunMicrotasks(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
32: 0x1046648ec v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::PerformCheckpoint(v8::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
33: 0x104284c4c node::InternalCallbackScope::Close() [/usr/local/bin/node]
34: 0x1042847bc node::InternalCallbackScope::~InternalCallbackScope() [/usr/local/bin/node]
35: 0x10435a76c node::fs::FileHandle::CloseReq::Resolve() [/usr/local/bin/node]
36: 0x104372f84 node::fs::FileHandle::ClosePromise()::$_0::__invoke(uv_fs_s*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
37: 0x104351734 node::MakeLibuvRequestCallback<uv_fs_s, void (*)(uv_fs_s*)>::Wrapper(uv_fs_s*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
38: 0x104d6ceac uv__work_done [/usr/local/bin/node]
39: 0x104d70908 uv__async_io [/usr/local/bin/node]
40: 0x104d82c6c uv__io_poll [/usr/local/bin/node]
41: 0x104d70ecc uv_run [/usr/local/bin/node]
42: 0x1042856fc node::SpinEventLoopInternal(node::Environment*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
43: 0x104395840 node::NodeMainInstance::Run(node::ExitCode*, node::Environment*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
44: 0x1043955ec node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/usr/local/bin/node]
45: 0x10432132c node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
46: 0x1856a90e0 start [/usr/lib/dyld]
Error: Command was killed with SIGABRT (Aborted): npm i prisma@5.9.1 -D
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance